# Linux C++, make application open terminal and run on it

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

I'm testing this on a basic *Hello World* C++ application.
Since I can see the std output only if running the application from terminal, I would like to let the application open its terminal by itself (when started by double clicking it), then execute the rest of the code on it.
I've already tried:

```
system("gnome-terminal");
```

just at the beginning of `main()` function.
The terminal opens but nothing gets displayed. I guess it's because it is opened on another thread... ?
So is there another way?

Comment: try popen to open a terminal and create a pipe that hooks your output to the programs input.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. You didn't create any method to communicate with the terminal. If you need bidirectional communication, you could create two pipes, one to go from your program to the terminal and one to go from the terminal to your program.
2. The way you called `system` causes your program to wait for `gnome-terminal` to exit. You need to put an `&` on the end. In practice, you probably don't want to use `system`. You'll need to hook the pipes up in-between the `fork` and the `exec`, so you shouldn't use `system` in the first place. Then you can just not wait.

If you want to be ugly, you can use the `/proc/self/fd/X` mechanism. For example, in theory this could work:

```
system("gnome-terminal < /proc/self/fd/%d > /proc/self/fd/%d &",
    terminal_fd_in, terminal_fd_out);
```

Just make sure the descriptors are *not* set to close on exec.

Comment: That's the thing I was trying to understand. I can not find anything in C++ about hooking the pipes after the fork or, in general, hooking an application to a terminal. That's why I asked here.
What would be the correct command sequence to use?

Comment: @leodedro Use `mkpipe` twice to make the two pipes. Then use `fork` to create another process. In the child process, hook up to one end of each pipe and then `exec`. In the parent, you can `dup2` the pipe ends over standard input and standard output.

Comment: One caution, this will hookup your standard input and standard output to pipes, not a terminal. If your program expects to interact with a terminal, then you will need to interpose a [pty](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pseudo_002dTerminal-Pairs.html) between the pipes and the `gnome-terminal` process.